# How to apply array formula taking data from another table?

Tags: google-sheets

We have two tables in Google Sheets.

First:

| Date | Amount | Currency | Worth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 100 | USD | 373 |
| 02.01.2021 | 100 | EUR | 451 |
| 03.01.2021 | 100 | PLN | 100 |
| 04.01.2021 | 100 | USD | 373 |
| 05.01.2021 | 100 | USD | 372 |

Second:

| Date | PLN | EUR | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | 1 | 4,50 | 3,73 |
| 02.01.2021 | 1 | 4,51 | 3,75 |
| 03.01.2021 | 1 | 4,50 | 3,74 |
| 04.01.2021 | 1 | 4,48 | 3,73 |
| 05.01.2021 | 1 | 4,49 | 3,72 |

I tried find array formula for first table, column Worth. Formula should take proper value from second table (based on two columns from table one - Date and Currency) and multiply that values by worth in column Amount. I really want to use array formula. Is it possible?

Comment: Add the expected result please

Comment: I added expected results...

Comment: @DigitalFarmer I thing you said "...and multiply that values by worth in column Amount." not by Amount in Worth column, Right!?

Comment: Hi @Osm I didn't say that, I think you made a mistake when tagging the user. But anyway, the expected result is in the ```Worth``` column.

Comment: @SławekZawadzki Correct me if I'm wrong but the accepted answer doesn't reflect the written question "...and multiply that values by worth in column Amount"

Comment: @SławekZawadzki the question need improvement in the last paragraph to clarify the desired output.

Comment: @Osm note that the initial question before editing already shows that ```Worth``` is blank, being the expected value and ```I tried find array formula for first table, column Worth.```. By saying that he wants to multiply the value of by ```Worth``` in ```Amount``` he meant to explain that by the formula used in ```Worth``` he already wants to take its value and multiply to ```Amount``` to get the final result. But I agree that I should adjust the last paragraph to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @DigitalFarmer Of course, the edit's vagueness inhibited me from updating my answer, Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `VLOOKUP` to find the correct date row and `MATCH` to find which column the value is in:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A,I2:L,MATCH(C2:C,I1:L1,0))*B2:B))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Option 01:** Getting the result with one cell one formula.
Paste this in `B3` "Amount" column in the first table, take a look at [this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K2y_TkpUJklhOJPFlAcq_mXQagk4dUydYQ7JgNo0DGc/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,G3:J,ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D="",,MATCH(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)+1)),0)))="",,ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,G3:J,ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D="",,MATCH(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)+1)),0)))*E3:E))
```

[image: Example]

**Explanation** ...
1 - [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)`(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)` To get the index you want to [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) the "Currency" column from the second table with, we need that in the next step.

2 - [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) the "date" found in First table `A3:A` from Range in the second table `G3:J`, with Index set to [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)`(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)`, and [is_sorted] set to `0`

3 - till now we have the value of the exchange rate if we can call it that for each Currency chosen in the first Table, we need to multiply it by Worth to get Amount
`ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,G3:J,ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D="",,MATCH(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)+1)),0)))*E3:E` is structured like this `Exchange rate * Amount`  note that `E3:E` is the Amount, and this [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)`(A3:A="",,` to calculate only when `A3:A` range is not blank.

4 - [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/search?q=ArrayFormula) and a [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) is needed to be wrapped around like this
 `ArrayFormula(IF(Range=Empty,Do nothing,formula)`

- Range:
  `ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,G3:J,ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D="",,MATCH(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)+1)),0)))`
- Empty
  `""`
- Do nothing :
  `,,`
- Formula:
  `ArrayFormula(IF(A3:A="",,VLOOKUP(A3:A,G3:J,ArrayFormula(IF(D3:D="",,MATCH(D3:D,$H$2:$J$2,0)+1)),0)))*E3:E`

**Option 02:** Getting the result with intermediate steps.

Same as option 01 but in seprate columns take a look at [this Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K2y_TkpUJklhOJPFlAcq_mXQagk4dUydYQ7JgNo0DGc/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]